# When I activate grid layout in ConTeXt, empty lines inexplicably appear

Tags: context, grids, grid-typesetting

What am I doing wrong? When I activate grid layout in ConTeXt, empty lines appear inside my paragraphs.

I activate the grid layout normally, through

```
\setuplayout[grid=yes]
```

and I get this (in page 17):

[image]

(I have not included the full source code because the empty lines appear after some pages of text, and also because I believe it must be a very common problem, since I wasn't able to avoid it even after removing all styling setup.)

Comment: Another closed question by the mouse-happy folks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your text contains characters (`À`) which are too tall for a line which result in an extra line in the output. To avoid the extra line you can increase the interlinespace

```
\setupinterlinespace[line=3ex]
```

or you can change the height/depth ratio of a line

```
\setupinterlinespace[height=0.8,depth=0.2]
```